# Why does it give me this notice?

Tags: php, sql

Who does:

```
echo $post['avg']
```

Give me:

```
Notice: Undefined index: avg in posts.php on line 39




SELECT p.id, p.message, p.poster, avg(r.rating)
FROM posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN userpostratings r ON p.id = r.postID
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userpostratings` (
`userID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`postID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`rating` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
KEY `userPostRatings_userID` (`userID`),
KEY `userPostRatings_postID` (`postID`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`message` text,
`poster` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`posted` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`topic_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The field is named `avg(r.rating)` not `avg`.

So `$post['avg(r.rating)']` would be correct (assuming you're storing the query results in $post), while `$post['avg']` would return a warning, because that index (`avg`) is never set or defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Use an alias in your query to make the name more friendly, like this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.message, p.poster, avg(r.rating) AS avg_rating
FROM posts p LEFT OUTER JOIN userpostratings r ON p.id = r.postID WHERE p.id = 1 GROUP BY p.id
```

Don't use `avg` as the alias, since this is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that notice because the your the `avg` index in your `$post` array is not defined. Note, this is not the same as data from your HTTP Post data, `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted the actual field name is "avg(r.rating)" usually its best to Tweak your SQL like so:

```
SELECT p.id, p.message, p.poster, avg(r.rating) as avgr
FROM posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN userpostratings r ON p.id = r.postID
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id
```

Then you can refer to the result of the function with the much more readable"

```
echo $post['avgr']
```

Answer (score -3):

Change it to

```
echo $_POST['avg']
```